# angular collapseAll not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap plugin to collapse and expand the `<div>`s. I am able to do it for individual `<div>`'s but if i leave one `<div>` expanded and do a `collapseAll()`, the expanded `<div>` only getting collapsed. Please provide me a solution on this

html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div class="panel-heading" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">{{item.title}}</div>
        <div class="panel-body" collapse="isCollapsed">{{item.content}}</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="collapse_all_cards" ng-model="isCollapsed"><label for="collapse_all_cards">Collapse All</label>
    </div>
</body>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{'title':'Item1','content':'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus maximus orci sodales, pellentesque urna eu'},
                {'title':'Item2','content':'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus maximus orci sodales, pellentesque urna eu'},

                 {'title':'Item3','content':'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus maximus orci sodales, pellentesque urna eu'}

            ]
});
```

link: http://plnkr.co/edit/mcnqeLJcTyaAuTI9JHb9

Answer (score 2):

Please see this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/UW65kGkFY2G9eOcEsHQW)

Pretty sure this is the behavour you are after :)

The problem before was that the same "isCollapsed" property on scope was being used for the "collapse all" and the individual collapses so they were tripping each other up.

See the new controller code which has an individual boolean "isCollapsed" property for each item in the collection:

```
{'title':'Item1','content':'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus maximus orci sodales, pellentesque urna eu', isCollapsed: true}
```

If you need any refinements to the code just ask :)